# find element index based of another element

Tags: jquery, html

am putting all images on a var gallery this ends up with and index of 35.
on click i want to find the index of an element based on element being displayed. i know is confusing but please look at the code.

```
var currentImg = gallery.indexOf($("#mainImg"));


<center>   
    <div id="main"> 
        <img id="mainImg" src="pictures/Front house.jpg" alt="not sure 
what this is"/> <br>
    </div> 
      <img class="next" src="pictures/arrow-left.png" alt=""/>   
<div id="gallery" >

    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/28.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/27.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/18.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/9.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/10.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/4.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/7.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/2.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/5.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/24.jpg" alt=""  >


    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/23.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/8.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/1.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/11.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/12.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/14.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/21.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/19.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/29.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/31.jpg" alt=""  >

    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/32.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/33.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/34.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/35.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/3.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/6.jpg"  alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/15.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/16.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/17.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/20.jpg" alt=""  >

    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/22.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/25.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/26.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/30.jpg" alt=""  >
    <img class="mySlides" src="pictures/33.jpg" alt=""  >




    </div>
      <img class="prev" src="pictures/arrow-right.png" alt=""/>
    </center>

//this is my js file
$("#gallery img").on({
    click: function(){
        var imageURL = $(this).attr('src');
        $("#mainImg").fadeOut(800, function (){
        $(this).attr("src", imageURL);
    }).fadeIn(800);}
});  

$(".next").click(nextPic);

function nextPic(){
    // get gallery picts
    var gallery = $(".mySlides");
    // get indexs of current picture
    var currentImg = gallery.indexOf($("#mainImg").attr('src'));
```

i want to be able to find the index of id=mainImg inside var gallery but i know am not setting this right. please help and explain

Comment: could you post all the code , html css , js ?

Comment: Can you please create snippet of it?

Comment: can you please try of `indexOf` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript `indexOf` method can't be used in your case. Using jQuery find and index method can be achieved easily.

```
function nextPic(){
    // get gallery pics
    var gallery = $(".mySlides");
    var attrSrc = $("#mainImg").attr('src'); // find src attr value of current img
    var mySlidesSel = $(".mySlides[src='"+attrSrc+"']"); // find the same img element from the slider
    var currentImg = gallery.index(mySlidesSel); // get indexs of that
    console.log(currentImg);
}
```

For working example: Check this Codepen link,
https://codepen.io/ntamil/pen/zyzMLe

Comment: thanks , not only for the answer the explanations help me learn it really appreciate it.